# I can't use vector in CAsyncSocket :: OnClose ()

Tags: c++, sockets, vector, mfc, asyncsocket

I am Working on a client/server Broadcast Application using CSocket. While client connect to server OnAccept Method call. In OnAccept method I am creating a object of that class and Store that pointer of object in vector.

```
void ServerSocket::OnAccept(int nErrorCode)
{
    ServerSocket * User = new ServerSocket;
    temp->m_hSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;   
    Accept(*temp);  
    m_vConnectionObject.push_back(temp);
    CSocket::OnAccept(nErrorCode);
}
```

While Client close the connection my OnClose method will be called but when I am trying to access my vector in that method, it shows me that my vector is empty.

```
void ServerSocket::OnClose(int nErrorCode)
{       
    CString cname,name;
    UINT cport,port;

    GetPeerNameEx(cname,cport);

    int i=m_vConnectionObject.size();      //here i got "i= 0"

    std::vector<ServerSocket *>::iterator it = (m_vConnectionObject).begin() ;
    for ( ; it != m_vConnectionObject.end(); ++it)
    {   
        (*it)->GetPeerNameEx(name,port);
        if ((name==cname) && (port==cport))
        {
            //erase code
        }
    }

    CSocket::OnClose(nErrorCode);

}
```

I want to access that vector to delete the pointer of disconnected client.

Comment: Your iterator loop is wrong. When `erase(it)` returns, the iterator `it` is no longer valid, and you must not pre-increment it. Instead, use `while(it != m_vConnectionObject.end()) { ... if( ... ) it = m_vConnectionObject.erase(it); else ++it;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing `OnAccept` in the context of the server's listen socket, but you are performing `OnClose` in the context of the client's socket. So you're looking at two different vectors.